# Custom prompt function not quite finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prompt

I'm working on a browserbased text-style game (it's a text game that uses some images/animations, but text to convey story/actions/commands).
I used to have it work through `prompt("What is your class?");` (Warrior, Wizard ETC), but wanted to create my own function for doing this to make it prettier.
Below some code:

```
/*
    1st value: Message being asked
    2nd value: input field being used
    3rd value: message block where question is presented
*/
var _cprompt = cPrompt('What is your class?', 'dialog-input', 'dialog-text');
alert(_cprompt);
```

And this is the actual function cPrompt();

```
/*
Custom prompt class
message: The message shown
inputField: The ID of the txtfield where the user inputs his answer
messageField: The textarea where the response appears
userInput: Empty variable to store the users input
*/

function cPrompt(mssg, inputFieldId, messageFieldId) {
    var message = mssg;
    var inputField = $('#'+inputFieldId);
    var messageField = $('#'+messageFieldId);
    var userInput = "";

    messageField.append(message);

    // Detect enter space being pressed in inputField
    inputField.keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            userInput = inputField.val();
        }
    });
}
```

So far so good, but I need it to stop other code from executing untill the user has filled in a response and has hit enter (similar to `prompt();`), so in this case it would not perform `alert(_cprompt);` untill the user has given some input and hit enter.

I tried making the function as dynamic as possible, but please feel free to add anything that might make it better/faster/easier to use.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"but I need it to stop other code from executing until the user has filled in a response and has hit enter"* **That is impossible with javascript.** your only real option is to use callbacks. You can't selectively stop parts of javascript. If you stop one part, you're stopping it all. And, when you stop it all, you're also stopping all user interaction with the page, making it impossible to add text to the text input.

Comment: Then how does prompt do it?

Comment: prompt is built into the browser, it isn't done with javascript.

Comment: You could prevent the user from interacting with the page using an overlay, but you can't stop the javascript from executing without also making it impossible for the user to use the text input.

Comment: Then instead of prompt like behaviour, what would I have to do to have a similar system? (text appears in chatscreen, user types answer, game possibly returns a response, code continues normally).

Comment: you can't. the *"code continues normally"* has to come before user types answer. Both of the provided answers show ways of doing this with callbacks instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a callback is a great way to perform an action after an event has occured. In this case the event would be 'the user filling in a response'. Check out a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/Q2qUK/2/.

```
<div id="dialog-text"></div>
<input id="dialog-input" />
```

In the cPrompt function, you can run the callback function just like any other function when the time is right. Instead of returning a value you pass the results as a parameter to the callback function.

```
function cPrompt(mssg, inputFieldId, messageFieldId, callback){
    var message = mssg;
    var inputField = $('#'+inputFieldId);
    var userInput = "";

    cNotify(messageFieldId, message);

    // Detect enter space being pressed in inputField
    inputField.on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            userInput = inputField.val();
            callback(userInput);

            // If you want the callback to only be executed once,
            // unbind the keyup event afterwards.
            inputField.off('keyup');

            // Empty the input field after processing the user's message.
            inputField.val('');
        }
    });
}
```

As an example of how to let your coding respond to the user input, I've created this cNotify function to show the user input in the dialog-text element.

```
function cNotify(messageFieldId, message){
    $('#' + messageFieldId).append('<div>' + message + '</div>');
}
```

To pass the callback use an anonymous function as a parameter to the cPrompt function.

```
cPrompt('What is your class?', 'dialog-input', 'dialog-text', function(_cprompt){

    // Here you put all the code you want to run after the user pressed enter.
    cNotify('dialog-text', _cprompt);
});
```

Comment: What would I do if I just want to save the result of cPrompt to a variable instead of alert'ing it?

Comment: You can put whatever code you want inside the anonymous callback function. The trick is to continue where you left off in the callback function, instead of immediately after you call the prompt function.

Comment: I wanted it to be simpeler to use, just like the original prompt function except with more parameters. If the project grows any more it will start becoming extremely cluttered.

Comment: Callback based programming is really the way to go when dealing with user interaction. To prevent your code from getting cluttered you should make use of functions.

Comment: I am making use of functions, that's why I'm writing one. I just want mine to be like prompt, except use my own made input field and div for showing text. I want it to be like prompt in a code sense aswell, just a simple line.

Comment: The prompt function blocks your entire browser from user interaction. The whole point of callbacks is to not do this. If you post some more of your code perhaps I can give you tips on how to keep it from getting cluttered.

Comment: I've decided to use a different method of user input, since this will eventually clash with other functionalities in my project. Your explanation is very clear and does solve the question, so I will accept it as the answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use callbacks.

```
function cPrompt(mssg, inputFieldId, messageFieldId, callback) {
    var message = mssg;
    var inputField = $('#'+inputFieldId);
    var messageField = $('#'+messageFieldId);

    messageField.append(message);

    // Detect enter space being pressed in inputField
    inputField.keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                callback(inputField.val());
            }
    });
}

cPrompt('What is your class?', 'dialog-input', 'dialog-text', function (_cprompt) {
    alert(_cprompt);
});
```

Comment: This is great, but for some reason it keeps spamming the alert(_cprompt);. Also, I don't want it to give me the alert(), that was just there to show me the value was properly returned by the function.